# How to configure IIS authentication password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a C# / ASP.NET web application in VS 2008 on a 32-bit XP.  I created a Login.aspx file for the user to enter a user name and password initially before seeing any data.  This functionality works now from VS.  I added users and roles by entering ASP.NET Configuration.

However, after publishing to IIS 6.0, the password does not work there.  How do I configure Directory Security in IIS for the same user name and password to work?

Comment: If your real name is Salvation that is a funny nickname.

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? It's refusing the authentication? you gen an error?

Comment: I mean that when I enter the password it says it is an invalid password although I know this same password works in VS.

Comment: Also would be great if you explain a little more your authentication code. As I said, make no sense to me that works "on VS" and not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using forms authentication the user information is probably on the database. This is not connected with IIS so I can think in 2 options

1) You're pointing to a different database that doesn't have the user you're logging in with.
2) An exception was threw related to the authentication process and on the exception handling code you're showing the message "invalid password".

**EDIT**

Here you have a complete example about how to use forms authentication with membershipprovider

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx

and here some more links about forms authentication

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm using forms authentication but I am a newbie to this.  Can you recommend any links describing this more?

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'll check them out!